# How to turn off html escape in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty3

I am using `html_checkboxes` for generating select menu. The problem is that in the checkbox name I have some html code and Smarty escapes it.

I have:

```
{html_checkboxes name='select_menu' values=$user_data[1] output=$user_data[2]}
```

I get:

```
Status: <span style="color: blue">Normal</span>
```

I need that status would be just blue.

Answer (score 11):

There is no correct answer above, even though  the last answer is quite close..

check this link out
http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/variable.escape.html.tpl

the correct answer should be `{$var nofilter}`

Comment: Please give a more detailed critique of the other answers, and explain why yours is better.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was `escape:false`

```
{html_checkboxes name='select_menu' values=$user_data[1] output=$user_data[2] escape:false}
```