# How to display HTML DOM elements which is sorted in TPL variable

Tags: php, smarty

Good morning,

I have variable with HTML code. For example:

```
{assign var="url" value="<a href='google.com'>URL</a>" nocache}
```

The next step is display the content.

```
{$url}
```

The result is:

```
<a href='google.com'>URL</a>
```

How to display the URL which will be a working link?

Kind regards

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351549/how-to-turn-off-html-escape-in-smarty, if it works then this can be marked as a dupe.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to add nofilter parameters to variable:

{$url nofilter}